# C# decorator pattern and wrapping issues

Tags: c#, decorator

I am having a problem wrapping my code return values. So basically I am trying to display the following output:

> *Morg, type*, xy, *paddle*

My code is in C#, and based on my code below, these outputs are based on my return values which are in string. I'm using them in hope to test my program to see if it works. Well so far it works but not the way I want. I only get to display the type return value, but I can't seem to display the rest of it.

This is what it gives me.

> *type*

But the one at the very top is the one I want to display as output. Not just the type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MorgReader myMorg = new FileReader();
            MorgReader myMorg2 = new MorgType(new MorgXY(new MorgMovement(new FileReader())));

            Console.WriteLine(myMorg.Read());
            Console.WriteLine(myMorg2.Read());

        }

    }

    // THE MAIN ABSTRACT CLASS //
    abstract class MorgReader
    {
        public abstract string Read();
    }

    //  THE CLASS THAT WILL READ THE FILE //
    class FileReader : MorgReader
    {
        public override string Read()
        {
            return "Morg";
        }
    }

    //  MY READER DECORATOR //

    abstract class ReaderDecorator : MorgReader
    {
        private MorgReader wrappedReader;
        protected ReaderDecorator(MorgReader wrapped)
        {
            wrappedReader = wrapped;
        }
        protected MorgReader WrappedReader
        { get { return wrappedReader; } }
    }

    class MorgType : ReaderDecorator
    {
        public MorgType(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
        { }

        public override string Read()
        {
            return "type";
        }
    }

    class MorgXY : ReaderDecorator
    {
        public MorgXY(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
        { }

        public override string Read()
        {
            return "x,y";
        }
    }

    class MorgMovement : ReaderDecorator
    {
        public MorgMovement(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
        { }

        public override string Read()
        {
            return "paddle";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ReaderDecorator` class

```
abstract class ReaderDecorator : MorgReader
{
    private MorgReader wrappedReader;
    protected ReaderDecorator(MorgReader wrapped)
    {
        wrappedReader = wrapped;
    }

    protected MorgReader WrappedReader
    { get { return wrappedReader; } }

    public override string Read()
    {
        var wrapped = WrappedReader.Read();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wrapped))
            wrapped += ", ";

        return wrapped + ReadImpl();
    }

    // template method
    protected abstract string ReadImpl();
}
```

Implement  `ReadImpl` in concrete class like this

```
class MorgType : ReaderDecorator
{
    public MorgType(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
    { }

    protected override string ReadImpl()
    {
        return "type";
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to introduce `ReadImpl` method, then you should override `Read` method in **every** concrete class like this

```
public override string Read()
{
    var wrapped = WrappedReader.Read();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wrapped))
        wrapped += ", ";

    return wrapped + "type";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your decorator pattern is missing... well, decorations (LOL). So decorate your abstract class descendants, like so:

```
class MorgType : ReaderDecorator
{
    public MorgType(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
    { }

    public override string Read()
    {
        return WrappedReader == null ? "type" : WrappedReader.Read() + ",type";
    }
}

class MorgXY : ReaderDecorator
{
    public MorgXY(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
    { }

    public override string Read()
    {
        return WrappedReader == null ? "x,y" : WrappedReader.Read() + ",x,y";
    }
}

class MorgMovement : ReaderDecorator
{
    public MorgMovement(MorgReader wrapped) : base(wrapped)
    { }

    public override string Read()
    {
        return WrappedReader == null ? "paddle" : WrappedReader.Read() + ",paddle";
    }
}
```

And you should see the result that you are expecting for `myMorg2`, which was a comma-delimited output that you described in your post.

Comment: Note that I personally hate the decorator pattern - this pattern should really be listed as an antipattern, because of all the evils it introduces. You'll soon agree, once you reach your first massive refactor event, which will surely happen if the pattern is ever used in a large project...

Comment: LOL! Oh believe me. I hate it with a passion already. But thank you so much for your help! I truly appreciate it!